# Mongodb all threads wait

Tags: mongodb

```
Thread 1253 (Thread 0x7e9e417b9700 (LWP 109033)):
#0  0x00007fa908b6c68c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000a1a6b4 in void boost::condition_variable_any::wait<boost::mutex>(boost::mutex&) ()
#2  0x0000000000a143ac in mongo::Lock::DBRead::lockTop(mongo::LockState&) ()
#3  0x0000000000a16763 in mongo::Lock::DBRead::lockDB(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#4  0x0000000000a17280 in mongo::Lock::DBRead::DBRead(mongo::StringData const&) ()
#5  0x00000000008f02d5 in mongo::Client::ReadContext::ReadContext(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#6  0x0000000000d4bcfa in mongo::newRunQuery(mongo::Message&, mongo::QueryMessage&, mongo::CurOp&, mongo::Message&) ()
#7  0x0000000000b97322 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000b99902 in mongo::assembleResponse(mongo::Message&, mongo::DbResponse&, mongo::HostAndPort const&) ()
#9  0x000000000076b6af in mongo::MyMessageHandler::process(mongo::Message&, mongo::AbstractMessagingPort*, mongo::LastError*) ()
#10 0x000000000117720b in mongo::PortMessageServer::handleIncomingMsg(void*) ()
#11 0x00007fa908b68aa1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#12 0x00007fa907f0dbcd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Thread 1252 (Thread 0x7e9e416b8700 (LWP 109034)):
#0  0x00007fa908b6c68c in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000a1a6b4 in void boost::condition_variable_any::wait<boost::mutex>(boost::mutex&) ()
#2  0x0000000000a143ac in mongo::Lock::DBRead::lockTop(mongo::LockState&) ()
#3  0x0000000000a16763 in mongo::Lock::DBRead::lockDB(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#4  0x0000000000a17280 in mongo::Lock::DBRead::DBRead(mongo::StringData const&) ()
#5  0x00000000008f02d5 in mongo::Client::ReadContext::ReadContext(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) ()
#6  0x0000000000d4bcfa in mongo::newRunQuery(mongo::Message&, mongo::QueryMessage&, mongo::CurOp&, mongo::Message&) ()
#7  0x0000000000b97322 in ?? ()
#8  0x0000000000b99902 in mongo::assembleResponse(mongo::Message&, mongo::DbResponse&, mongo::HostAndPort const&) ()
#9  0x000000000076b6af in mongo::MyMessageHandler::process(mongo::Message&, mongo::AbstractMessagingPort*, mongo::LastError*) ()
#10 0x000000000117720b in mongo::PortMessageServer::handleIncomingMsg(void*) ()
#11 0x00007fa908b68aa1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#12 0x00007fa907f0dbcd in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Most of the mango threads are waiting, all operations are blocked, the correct response results can not be obtained, the specific causes are not clear.

More detailed thread stack in stack.log file.
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-3095

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:477)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:228)
at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.receiveMessage(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:96)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.receiveMessage(DefaultConnectionPool.java:440)
at com.mongodb.connection.QueryProtocol.execute(QueryProtocol.java:289)
at com.mongodb.connection.QueryProtocol.execute(QueryProtocol.java:54)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor.execute(DefaultServer.java:168)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.executeProtocol(DefaultServerConnection.java:289)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerConnection.query(DefaultServerConnection.java:212)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:525)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation$1.call(FindOperation.java:510)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:435)
at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:408)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:510)
at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:81)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:836)
at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:823)
at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl$FindOperationIterable.first(FindIterableImpl.java:216)
at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:156)
at com.memeyule.cryolite.repository.RedPacketRepository.find(RedPacketRepository.kt:29)
at com.memeyule.cryolite.repository.RedPacketRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$49e1f1de.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
```

In the current mango jam, a lot of errors have been reported in the application.

Comment: `com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message`. Is mongodb server running, if yes is it accessible from your app server?  Looks like it waiting for connection but failed to connect to mongodb server withing timeoutException

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)